# How to combine javascript and node.js in the correct way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow

I want to apply PoseNet(https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet) on a set of images. I have however, never used javascript or node.js. So far I have a .html file which can generate a result from the pretrained model for one image that is in the same directory. However, I can only access the result by (manually) copying from the browser console.

I would like to:

1. Be able to save the object to a file.
2. Loop this through all images in a folder and append to said file.

When looking for solutions I got the impression that javascript is not a good fit for this, but I should use node instead. I was wondering if I can make a node file, that makes use of my other .html script or if I have to switch to a node only solution?

**This is not a main problem, just a different path I've tried:**
I have tried to get the same result for one picture via using node, but I run into the following error: `Error: Cannot find module '/home/user/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/lib/napi-v3/tfjs_binding.node'`. Which I believe stems from the installation via `sudo npm i @tensorflow/tfjs-node`. There I get `(node:16006) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/user/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/deps'`.

**Coming back to my main problem**, my code looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img id='image' src='image.jpg '/>
  </body>
</html>
  <script>
    var flipHorizontal = false;

    var imageElement = document.getElementById('image');

    posenet.load().then(function(net) {
      const pose = net.estimateSinglePose(imageElement, {
        flipHorizontal: true
      });
      return pose;
    }).then(function(pose){
      console.log(pose);
    })
  </script>
</html>
```

Is there a way to use node in an additional .js file to call this html script for different image and write the objects into a file?

Comment: "Is there a way to use node in an additional .js file " — Node is a tool for executing JS. In this context it is an alternative to using a web browser. You cannot load it into a web browser.

Comment: So basically you'll want to do: 1) a Node.js tutorial. 2) learn importing modules so you can import filesystem and tensorflow. 3) learn the node filesystem module to fetch the images from a hard disk. 4) Loop over all the images using tensorflow. 5) Use the results some way.

Comment: @Shilly Thanks! I need to fix the tfjs-node installation problem then I assume?

Comment: Probably. But it looks to me that the error is just write access when trying to copy the library to your project. So you might have to reinstall it correctly. Worst case, just start a fresh node_modules for this project and install all the dependencies using a npm guide so you are sure your package.json file is correct.

Comment: Would you recommend reinstalling from scratch and using nvm?